# Framebuffer texture not getting passed to shader and not showing on screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, framebuffer

I'm writing a program that can composite two images through shaders and save the result locally. Simply outputting to the viewport would cut offscreen pixels and I wanted to make it windowless, so I tried going with Framebuffer objects for offscreen rendering.

I tried writing prototype project to understand FBOs and show a single texture on screen, but the result is just a blank background colored viewport, like so:[image: imgur]. Funnily enough that background color gets shaded properly in the frag shader if I change the color values, but any kind of texture from the framebuffer just won't be visible or doesn't get passed to the shader at all.

here's my code:

main.cpp

```
const char* img1_path = "C:/..path../img_00001.jpg";
const char* img2_path = "C:/..path../img_00002.jpg";

GLfloat square_vertices[] =
{ //     COORDINATES     /        COLORS      /   TexCoord  //
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Lower left corner
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, // Upper left corner
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // Upper right corner
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f  // Lower right corner
};

GLuint square_indices[] =
{
    0, 2, 1, // Upper triangle
    0, 3, 2 // Lower triangle
};

// for FBO
static const GLfloat g_quad_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 1;
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720

int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // usiamo il core profile

    // create glfwwindow
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGL();
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);


    // VAO init
    GLuint VAO1;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO1);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO1);

    // my custom texture (1920x1080)
    int widthImg, heightImg, numColCh;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load(img1_path, &widthImg, &heightImg, &numColCh, 0);

    // shader reading, compiling and linking
    Shader shaderProgram(vert_path, frag_path);

    // Texture setup
    GLuint Texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);

    // shader uniform linking
    GLuint TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "tex0");

    // VBO
    GLuint VBO1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square_vertices), square_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // EBO
    GLuint EBO1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO1);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square_indices), square_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // FBO
    // framebuffer
    GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    GLuint renderedTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // depth buffer
    GLuint depthrenderbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

    // Set list of draw buffers.
    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

    // Error checking framebuffer
    auto fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Framebuffer error: " << fboStatus << std::endl;

    // FBO vertices
    GLuint quad_vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_buffer_data), g_quad_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    Shader quad_program(FB_vert, FB_frag);
    GLuint texID = glGetUniformLocation(quad_program.ID, "FBtex");


    // LOOP
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        // non-FBO shader
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram.ID);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // bind EBO
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO1);

        // drawelements
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // FBO shader
        glUseProgram(quad_program.ID);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glUniform1i(texID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangles
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VAO1);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO1);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO1);
    shaderProgram.Delete();
    quad_program.Delete();
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

FBO.vert (passthrough)

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoords;

out vec2 texCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inPos.x, inPos.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
    texCoords = inTexCoords;
}
```

FBO.frag

```
#version 460 core

in vec2 texCoords;
out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D FBtex;

void main()
{
    vec3 temp = texture(FBtex, texCoords).xyz;
    color = temp;

    // this works and shades the blue background color
    //color = vec3(temp.x + 0.3f, temp.y + 0.3f, temp.z + 0.3f);
}
```

I'm stumped, I just recently learned opengl and there are still many things that confuse me that I don't know how to navigate around such as the order of the functions and the internal state machine, so if you can please answer as exhaustively and foolproof as you can. I followed many tutorials on FBOs, many of which have very similar code but the texture just won't show up on screen.

bonus questions:

Is a depth buffer necessary to use the framebuffer even if I only need textures? and if it is, are a camera + 3D model implementations necessary as well?

Would glFramebufferTexture2D() help instead of glFramebufferTexture()?

Answer (score -3):

You need to render the Texture and not the RenderedTexture. You also need to add the TexParameters. Then you can render the texture to a quad, then you can use glFramebufferTexture to render the texture the framebuffer and finally render the texture again to a quad.

The depth buffer and the camera model are not necessary and you can use glFramebufferTexture or glFramebufferTexture2D.

```
int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // usiamo il core profile

    // create glfwwindow
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGL();
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);


    // VAO init
    GLuint VAO1;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO1);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO1);

    // my custom texture (1920x1080)
    int widthImg, heightImg, numColCh;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load(img1_path, &widthImg, &heightImg, &numColCh, 0);

    // shader reading, compiling and linking
    Shader shaderProgram(vert_path, frag_path);

    // Texture setup
    GLuint Texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // shader uniform linking
    GLuint TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "FBtex");

    // VBO
    GLuint VBO1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square_vertices), square_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // EBO
    GLuint EBO1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO1);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square_indices), square_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // FBO
    // framebuffer
    GLuint FramebufferName;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    GLuint renderedTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // depth buffer
    GLuint depthrenderbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);

    

    // FBO vertices
    GLuint quad_vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_quad_vertex_buffer_data), g_quad_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    Shader quad_program(FB_vert, FB_frag);
    GLuint texID = glGetUniformLocation(quad_program.ID, "FBtex");


    // LOOP
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        //glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

        // non-FBO shader
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram.ID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangles
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
        glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, Texture, 0);
        // Set list of draw buffers.
        GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
        glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

        // Error checking framebuffer
        auto fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            std::cout << "Framebuffer error: " << fboStatus << std::endl;
        
        // Render to the screen
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     
        glUseProgram(quad_program.ID);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glUniform1i(texID, 0);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangles
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VAO1);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO1);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO1);
    shaderProgram.Delete();
    quad_program.Delete();
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad_vertexbuffer);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```